# What does xdata section do?

Tags: c++, c, coff

I have a simple `hello world` program and after i **dumpbin** it with */headers* flag, i get this output:

```
FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
               D number of sections
        5A3D287F time date stamp Fri Dec 22 18:45:03 2017
             48F file pointer to symbol table
              2D number of symbols
               0 size of optional header
               0 characteristics

Summary

           F .data
          A0 .debug$S
          2F .drectve
          24 .pdata
          B9 .text$mn
          18 .xdata
```

What exactly xdata section do and what it contains? No info on msdn.

Comment: Do you know if your simple program source is C or C++? Do you know the difference?

Comment: @usr2564301 what's your point? i'm compiling the program with /TC.

Comment: The point is that C and C++ are different languages! If you don't know what you are using, then look at the file extension of your source code. If it's `.c` then you are programming in C. If it's `.cpp` then you are using C++. Check and delete the inappropriate tag.

Comment: Good question @Tracy. I am looking now at an exe file for a c program and it has an xdata section. Did you ever get any info on what an xdata section is?

Comment: @Jongware C++ is just a bunch of abstraction bloat over C, so they are the same languages at the core.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference:

- .text: codesegment (think functions); there can be multiple of those when enabling function sections or when comdat is involved (for example templates)
- .data: datasegment (think global vars); there can be multiple of those when enabling data sections or when comdat is involved (for example templates)
- .bss:  datasegment initialized to zeros (not present above); there can be multiple of those when enabling data sections or when comdat is involved (for example templates)
- .debug: Debug info; like others, there can be multiple of these when function sections are involved.
- .pdata: for x86_64, this is the "exception info" for a method, it defines the start/end of a function, and a pointer to the unwind info (see .xdata); inside object files this is duplicated per function
- .drectve: not sure; but from the name I'd guess linker directives.
- .xdata: for x86_64; this is the unwind info part that pdata points to. It contains where the exception handler of a function is, and what to do to unwind it when an exception occurs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exception-handling-x64?view=vs-2019

The "$" postfix is used for sorting. Given:
- .sec$z
- .sec$data
- .sec$a

The sections are sorted before they are merged into an executable (so .sec$a first, then data, then z), this can be used to create start/end symbols to a pe section.

Answer (score 0):

The repeated sections are for things like c++ templates, the compiler will instantiate a template in any translation unit that needs it and then the linker will pick one of those instantiations (usually the first encountered).

Less common are compiler-specific features like Microsoft's __declspec(selectany) that allow a variable to be defined more than once and again the linker will simply pick one of those definitions and discard the rest.

gcc's ld scripts will take all the .text* sections to create the final .text of the linked executable. You can examine those scripts to get an idea of how the linker creates an executable out of object files.